# Twitter Follow button won’t show username when in dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter

Take a normal follow button with a username from https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#follow

Put it inside normal bootstrap dropdown like this http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/417/ and it will render without the username.

```
              <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">Dropdown</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="https://twitter.com/wikibudgets" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @wikibudgets</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
               </div>

<br>
<br>


<a href="https://twitter.com/wikibudgets" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @wikibudgets</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

There is identical button rendered below the dropdown to show it works correctly outside of the dropdown.

**EDIT**
I am using latest Chrome (38.0) on OSX. The issue does not manifest on latest Firefox.

Comment: What browser are you using? On firefox 33, the button inside the dropdown is the same as below it (in your fiddle that is).

Comment: I've edited the question to provide more details, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: If the answer is not obvious, I'd try checking the html inside firefox developer tools and check css rules applied etc. and do the same on chrome and see what html/css is different, not applied, has no effect or missing, etc. Then the question becomes "why does chrome ignore padding rule" for example, to get you closer.

Comment: The content of the button is rendered by Twitter's JavaScript, the @username is simply not there, it's not a question of CSS or HTML. AS far as I can tell. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer somewhere, the button will not render correctly if drawn while not visible. I had to change my code so that the button is drawn only after the user opens the dropdown.